# how can I make a child of a div with display:flex, scroll down in small resolution?

Tags: css

I have a container with `display:flex`, and I have 3 children.  I want that when the text of the first div does not occupy a single line:

[image]

, the last container is moved down, something like this:

how can do it?

[image]

```css
.flex{
 display:flex;
 width:100%;
 border:1px solid red;
}

.flex div{
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="longtext">By Team Developers People</div>
  <div>1 min</div>
  <div>26, Feb 2022</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is achievable using `flex-wrap`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow`, you can read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (recommended).

here is an example; you should tweak it so it will fit your needs

```
.flex{
 display:flex;
 width:100%;
 border:1px solid red;
 flex-flow: row wrap;  
 align-items: center;
}

.flex div{
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:100%;
  flex: 1 1 160px;
}
```

---

the three numbers in the flex property stands for `flex-grow` `flex-shrink` `flex-basis` (in corresponding order). you don't have to declare all of them, and you can use them separately.

##### flex-grow

A number specifying how much the item will grow relative to the rest of the flexible items

##### flex-shrink

A number specifying how much the item will shrink relative to the rest of the flexible items

##### flex-basis

The length of the item

Comment: this not works for me, what means flex: 1 1 160px? in specific 160px?

Comment: i've added an explanation in my answer :)